# Simple RNN in Torch

Tags: torch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a RNN in Torch. To get used to it I start with a simple task of predicting the next item in the sequences. Sequences are subsequences of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} with an offset chosen randomly.

I want to implement a network architecture with one hidden layer with LSTM cells. That is why I use nn.SeqLSTM(inputsize, outputsize)

```
rho = 5 -- number of steps for bptt
hiddensize = 15
inputsize = 1
outputsize = 1
seqlen = 5
nIndex = 10
batchsize = 4

seqlstm = nn.SeqLSTM(inputsize, outputsize)
criterion = nn.SequencerCriterion(nn.ClassNLLCriterion())


outputs = seqlstm:forward(inputs) -- inputs is seqlen x batchsize x inputsize
err = criterion:forward(outputs, targets) -- targets is seqlen x batchsize x 1
```

- Do I need a nn.LookupTable?
- This code seems a bit to simple and is missing some glue I guess. However which parts are missing to make it complete?

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is not your whole code, there is quite a bit missing, not just glue.

1- Having an input and output size of 1 for an LSTM layer does not make much sense

2- I wouldn't mess around with rho unless you really want your network to backpropagate for 5 timesteps only

3- [ClassNLLCriterion](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/criterion.md#nn.ClassNLLCriterion) expects log probabilities as input

4- You need an optimization algorithm in order to actually train your network such as SGD (see the [optim](https://github.com/torch/optim) library by torch)

5- Usually you atleast need an input layer and an output layer in a network. The input layer will transforms your input into embeddings that will then be forwarded through your hidden layer(s) which could be an LSTM layer. A LookupTable can be used in the input layer. The output layer could potentially form a probability distribution over your possible outputs using a softmax layer.

6- It is indeed a little too simple

nn.LookupTable is a module that stores embeddings for your input. For example, if you're trying to predict the next character in a sequence, then you could have a LookupTable of size 26xinDim where you have an embedding of size inDim for each character in the alphabet. You could indeed probably use one.

Looking at this, I suspect that you might not be entirely familiar with how neural networks are built. I suggest you familiarize yourself a little bit more before jumping in. [Here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com) is a very nice book by Michael Nielsen about deep learning. He explains everything very intuitively.

Looking at examples from Element-Research/rnn or torch/nn is also very helpful. Karpathy's [char-rnn](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn) is also interesting.

I hope this is of any help.